# Complete transaction with multiple dao in service class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, dao

How do I achieve a complete transaction where a service class requires more than one data access object. Assuming I have the following structure.

Currently, if my dao2 failed, the dao1 still being committed to the database which I do not want it to happen. However, I need my DAO to be reusable.

```
public class mainService(){
  dao1.store(obj1);
  dao2.store(obj2);
}
```

And my dao is written in this way.

Dao 1

```
private EntityManager entityManager;
@Transactional
public void store(Object obj1){
  entityManager.persist(obj1);
}
```

Dao 2

```
private EntityManager entityManager;
@Transactional
public void store(Object obj2){
  entityManager.persist(obj2);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Make this happen in one transaction.

```
@Transactional
public void mainService(..){
  dao1.store(obj1);
  dao2.store(obj2);
}
```

Only one transaction will be created, and if dao2 fails, dao1 won't be committed as well. And remove `@Transactional` from `store` method. Making DB level methods transactional it's not a good idea. This level might be two low in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to use:

```
private EntityManager entityManager;
@Transactional
public void store(Object obj1, Object obj2){
    entityManager.persist(obj1);
    entityManager.persist(obj2);
}
```

What's happened is that you have become hung up on using DAOs. The DAO is dead! If you look at the EntityManager API you will notice that it actually looks very much like a DAO type of interface. So just use it directly where ever you would normally consider using a DAO.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should mark mainService() with @Transactional too,  For transaction propagation rule is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED by default , and then both dao1.store() and dao2.store() with be under the same transaction.It's OK to keep dao1.store() and dao2.store() @Transactional, they will realize that there is already a transaction and then join the transaction.

Comment: Do you mean something like @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) on the service class?